# Ensure properties are overridden in subclasses, without losing read-only variables

Tags: python, python-3.10

Using the code below, I should be able to create a subclass `Sub()` that ensure the following:

1. Ensure that every property is overridden in the subclass, either by defining it as a class variable (e.g. `security_enabled` ) or by overriding it as an instance variable (e.g. `display_name`).
2. Protect the subclass from accidentally added instance variables. (e.g. `foo`)
3. Protect the subclass from changing values that are class variables (e.g. `security_enabled`)
4. Support Python 3.10

This code almost fulfills all requirements, except for (1). How can I implement that requirement? Ideally, there would be a way to allow certain properties to only be allowed to be overridden as class XOR instance variables.

Background: The subclasses should implement different "flavours" of the dataclass, where `display_name` and `description` are individually set with each instantiation, and `security_enabled` has a default value per SubClass, that must never be changed (even by accident).

```py
@dataclass(slots=True)
class EntraGroup:
    # Allow parameter values
    display_name: constr(max_length=256)
    # Allow parameter values
    description: constr(max_length=1000)
    # Must be overriden in subclass
    security_enabled: bool


class Sub(EntraGroup):
    __slots__ = []
    security_enabled = True

    def __init__(
        self,
        display_name: str,
        # description: str,
    ):
        self.display_name = display_name
        # self.description = description


s = Sub(
    display_name="My Group",
    # description="A group to test some stuff.",
)
```

1. I need help with this requirement. The code below did not override `description`, but the subclass can be instantiated.
2. Works:

```
s.foo = "bar"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Sub' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

3. Works:

```
s.security_enabled = False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Sub' object attribute 'security_enabled' is read-only
```